# (Entity) Linq Group By statement type conversion

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, type-conversion, entity

I am having trouble converting the list type from group by statement back to the type I can use.

I know group by adds a key to the list but how do I get rid of it and it my case convert it back to `List<UserAnswers>` ? Can anybody provide some insights or point me in the right direction?

```
        public async Task<List<UserAnswers>>
    GetQuestionsWellAsync(string UserName) // get questions
        {
            return await ctx.UserAnswers.Where(x => x.UserId == UserName && x.Correct == 1).
                GroupBy(c => c.QuestionId).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 2).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why would you group it if you want to then re-flatten the grouping?

Comment: Please see edit :-), I want to find answers which have been answered correctly more than 2 times

Comment: Which EF Core version? Such query supported from EF Core 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.SelectMany()` to flatten your groupings back out into a single aggregated list.

```
public async Task<List<UserAnswers>> GetQuestionsWellAsync(string UserName)
{
    return await ctx.UserAnswers
        .Where(x => x.UserId == UserName && x.Correct == 1)
        .GroupBy(c => c.QuestionId)
        .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 2)
        .SelectMany(grp => grp)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Based on your update, it seems like EF cannot translate the GroupBy + Where Count() expression. You may need to project the grouped data into memory first and then filter.

```
public async Task<List<UserAnswers>> GetQuestionsWellAsync(string UserName)
{
    return (await userAnswers
        .Where(x => x.UserId == UserName && x.Correct == 1)
        .GroupBy(c => c.QuestionId)
        .ToListAsync())
        .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 2)
        .SelectMany(grp => grp)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: i still get the following error: ```Severity Code Description Project Project Rank File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<Words.Data.Models.UserAnswers>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Words.Data.Models.UserAnswers>' Words 1 C:\Users\Kevq\source\repos\Words\Words\Data\AppService.cs 37 Active
   ```

Comment: @KevinGrajewski did you notice the `await` keyword in my answer? You MUST await the response to get a result from Task.

Comment: Oh sorry David! I swear it was there before, but I tried this method this evening and I am getting the same error as I did about an hour ago trying this. Do you know what might be happening here? ```                                                            InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<UserAnswers>() ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.  ```